# Implementing websockets in microservices application

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, websocket

I have a pretty complicated excercise, but I have managed well so far. Only thing left for me to do is add WebSockets to the mix.

It's a simple voting app on two topics, but I have to use specific technologies to use on specific parts. Also, everything is running in Docker.

Here is the architecture of my application:

[image: architecture]

Currently the application works on HTTP requests, but I have to implement WebSockets somehow. I know I have to link Angular, but what's the other one?

How would I implement WebSockets in this case?

Comment: You can add a web socket, but the question is why do you need it? Does it add value to your app?

Comment: It's part of the exercise, the simple voting app could be done much easily, I know.

"Results API should be implemented in NodeJS. Component is responsible of the results part of the app.
Interface for communicating to frontend should be WebSockets."

From this I take that I should link it with NodeJS, but how would that work?

Comment: Ok, so maybe you need to do a real time update in your UI? There are plenty of tutorials on how to do it, like this one https://flaviocopes.com/websockets/

Comment: Yeah but like, data is coming from one place and I have to send it to another. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websockets have a lot in common with https. In fact, they start their lives as https connections and then get *upgraded* to persistent websocket connections.

So, your client (Javascript in your browser) initiates a connection using an instance of the [WebSocket object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications).   Then it can send and receive messages to and from the server. Your browser code might look like this. It initiates a connection. When the connection opens it sends a message.

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com:8090/socketserver");

ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log ('incoming', event.data);
}

ws.onopen = function (event) {
    ws.send ("Hey there server!");
}
```

On the server (nodejs) side you need to rig up a websocket server to accept your client connections. You can do this with [npm's ws package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws). (There are other packages, but I known this one works.)

Your minimum viable ws server code is pretty simple too.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
... 
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8090 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  /* Here an incoming websocket connection is accepted 
   * You must keep the ws object in scope for the lifetime
   * of the connection */

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  /* respond to ping keepalives from client */
  ws.on('ping', function ping() {
      ws.pong();
  }

  /* send messages as needed */
  ws.send('hey there client!');
});
```

Notice this: browser security doesn't allow you to mix connection modes (https / http) from browsers to servers. So if the rest of your front  end is served via https:, you'll need to use wss: instead of ws:.  It's a little harder to rig on the server side, but still works the same way.

Also notice that I haven't given any error or timeout handling. Production code needs those things.